# How to secure simple configuration in plain scala project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a few properties that I want to protect from just lying in my class, just string properties for now, for example:

```
class MyClass {

   protected val dbTableName: String = "employees" 

}
```

is there a more secure way to put this configuration in somewhere?

in play framework i used Configuration file and then I could use `.getString` or whatever, but in this case I dont have play and I want to make it cleaner and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) which is what Play uses internally.

With an `application.conf` file in your `src/main/resources` looking like:

```
db {
  table {
    name = employees
  }
}
```

You can then load it up on your Scala code like this:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

val conf = ConfigFactory.load();
val dbTableName = conf.getString("db.table.name")
```

Comment: i tried it but i cant import `import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory`
 from some reason, it just intellij dosent accept it...

Comment: did you add `libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
` to your `build.sbt`?